# Having trouble using async await with Google Maps Geocode API

Tags: node.js, async-await, google-geocoder

I'm using the Google Maps Geocode API and attempting to use async await. I've defined several functions for handling the request:

```
function googleGeoCode(address) {
  const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: 'googleMapsApiKeyGoesHere',
    Promise: Promise
  });

  return googleMapsClient.geocode({ address: address }).asPromise();
}

async function getGeoCode(address, errors, res) {
  try {
    const result = await googleGeoCode(address);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    errors.googleMapsClient = error;
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }
}
```

I then use the getGeoCode function in my express route:

```
const geoResponse = getGeoCode(req.body.address, errors, res);
```

The await portion of the function is not working correctly. If i console log geoResponse I get `Promise { <pending> }`

I'm new to using async await and I'm not sure if I am doing something incorrect here. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An async function always returns a promise or wraps the return value into promise,you have to resolve the promise like this

```
 const geoResponse = getGeoCode(req.body.address, errors, res);

    geoResponse.then((result)=>{

    console.log(result)
    }).catch((err)=>{
     console.log(err);
    })
```